# Different space between simple directive and same directives in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

**The problem is**:
There were big space between simple directive and the same directives in ngRepeat (in case of `display: inline-block` and chrome browser)

[Here the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zSTaOyLDt6HmQD9ROcJ9?p=preview)

1. I can add an unlimited directives and everything will be Ok:

```html
<tile></tile>
<tile></tile>
<tile></tile>
<tile></tile>
```

2. But If I write something like `ngRepeat`, layout will be broken:

```html
<tile></tile>
<tile></tile>
<tile></tile>
<!-- Here will be too big space-->
<tile ng-repeat="t in [0, 1, 2, 3]"></tile>
```

Here directive's code:

```js
 .directive('tile', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            template: '<div class="tile"></div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {},
            link: function (scope) {}
        };
    })
```

directive css class `.tile`:

```
.tile {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So, why does it happens? What's the reason, and how do I fight against this?

Comment: Remove the whitespace between tags. Display inline-block considers the whitespaces between the elements. [See here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespace between tags. Display inline-block considers the whitespaces between the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float: left`; to your css please see demo below

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.directive('tile', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="tile"></div> ',
    controller: function($scope) {

    },
    link: function(scope) {


    }
  };
});
```

```css
.tile {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app'>

  <div class="wrap">

    <tile></tile>
    <tile></tile>
    <tile ng-repeat="t in [0, 1, 2, 3]"></tile>

  </div>
</body>
```